# Tomcat is not running other programs with administrator rights

Tags: java, tomcat, access-denied

I have `program1.jar` and when I am running it using **cmd** it works great. This program "doing something" and then write result to remote ftp eg.

> \11.4.0.122\resultfolder

Now I created `tomcatprogram.war` and deploy it on Tomcat. `tomcatprogram.war` was created for running `program1.jar`.

And here is the problem, when I try to run `program1.jar` by Tomcat (`tomcatprogram.war`) I can not save anything in ftp, because "access is denied".

It looks like Tomcat have not administrator rights.

Any idea repair that ?

Edit:
I am running tomcat through windows services

Comment: If you launch `program1.jar` from Tomcat using `Runtime.exec()` or similar, it will run as the same user account that runs Tomcat.  If you're having problems sending files by FTP, I doubt that whatever rights the Tomcat process has are particularly relevant.

Comment: Why would the access rights of the local process running your code have *any* impact at all on the FTP connection to a remote server?

Comment: Sorry, there is a VPS with Linux. I have no idea, why it doest work through Tomcat